# How to draw dynamic number of tables

Tags: asp.net, webforms

what is the asp.net (not mvc) to generate a dynamic number of tables in aspx page. all HTML tables have the same data structure. the content is collected on server by a foreach loop. each iteration should produce a HTML table.

in MVC i would iterate a list of viewmodel and call partial view for drawing the table
what to do in asp.net webforms?

Comment: just generate the html string and parse it at the client side. google "adding raw html string aspx". but i think aspx elements have embedded functions for adding new elements. google "adding elements to html aspx". good luck

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the table, that could possibly lead to some unreadable server-side code. I don't know if this is a personal preference thing or not, but I avoid creating HTML fragments in C# unless I have no other option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following classes `HtmlTable`, `HtmlTableRow` and `HtmlTableCell` to create dynamic html table as follow

suppose I have a div in my html page

```
<div id='div1' runat='server'>
</div>
```

In code behind you can do like this

```
HtmlTable myTable = new HtmlTable();
HtmlTableRow row;
HtmlTableCell cell;
int numrows = 8;
int numcells = 7;
for (int j = 0; j < numrows; j++) 
{
    HtmlTableRow r = new HtmlTableRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < numcells; i++) 
    {
       HtmlTableCell c = new HtmlTableCell();  
       r.Cells.Add(c);
    }
    Table1.Rows.Add(r);
 }
```

and then finally you can add this control in any other control as

```
 div1.Controls.Add(Table1);
```

Some Useful links

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2962t2k8(v=vs.85).aspx
2. [Creating a dynamic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271171/creating-a-dynamic-table)

Answer (score 0):

Use nested Repeaters, an outer one for generating each `<TABLE>` and the inner one to generate the contents of each table.